# schedule job using cron expression

Tags: batch, schedulebatch, cron

How we can execute/schedule job **every month's first week of saturday** using cron expression.

```
 0 0 13 * * ?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use below CRON expression.

```
0 0 12 ? 1/1 SAT#1 *
```

I just tested this in my org and it seems working.
[image]

You can use http://www.cronmaker.com/?1 to generate this easily in future.
[image]